# Socket.io and Node.js Chatroom with admin area

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am making a chat room with socket and node, I want an admin area, so lets say the chat is at localhost:3000. I don't want the admin area to be /admin for obvious security reasons I am very new to socket and node in fact this is the first app I am creating using these technologies..

So what would be the best solution for a secure admin area..? This has to be done quite quickly and the app has no database so I think a login would be out of the question.. or I could have a login with a static username and password? Is this secure..? I am really not too sure.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Implementing login would be the best option here. If you are not using any database, you can rely on alternate storing mechanism like in-memory storage or file systems storage to save admin credentials. It is up to your requirement whether to use persistent or non-persistent storage meshanism.
You may use npm modules like `bcrypt` to hash passwords while saving in storage, if you want to implement security.

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
   bcrypt.hash(myPassword,salt,function(err,hash){//use the hashed value 'hash' here
   });
});
```

This will defend from threats like [Rainbow Table Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).